# can i open .bracket file using python?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, data-science

can i open .bracket file using python?I tried to make tree using nltk. 
If its only 1 sentence i have no problem, for example:

```
s = '(S (NP (DT the) (NN cat)) (VP (VBD ate) (NP (DT a) (NN cookie))))'
t = Tree.fromstring(s)
print("Convert bracketed string into tree:")
print(t)
print(t.__repr__())
```

But i have hundreds of sentence which is in a .bracket file example:

```
(S (SBAR (IN Kendati) (S (NP (-NONE- *)) (VP (MD sempat) (VP (VB membantah) (NP (PRP nya)))))) (Z ,) (CC namun) (NP (NNP Tjandra)) (NP (RB akhirnya)) (VP (VB mengakui) (SBAR (IN jika) (S (ADVP (RB memang)) (NP (NNP Pinnacle)) (VP (VB berencana) (S (NP (-NONE- *-1)) (VP (VB mengakuisisi) (NP (NNP Toba) (NNP Pulp)))))))) (Z .))
(SINV (SBAR-TPC-1 (Z ") (IN Sehingga) (S (NP (NP (NN rasio) (NN utang) (NN pemerintah)) (PP (IN pada) (NP (NN akhir) (CD 2008)))) (VP (VB diperkirakan) (S (NP (-NONE- *-2)) (VP (VB turun) (S (NP (-NONE- *-3)) (VP (VB menjadi) (NP (QP (RB sekitar) (CD 33,0) (NN persen))))))))) (Z ,) (Z '')) (VP (VB ujar) (SBAR (-NONE- *T*-1))) (NP (NN Presiden)) (Z .))
etc.
```

i tried using :

```
s = open(r'file.bracket')
t = Tree.fromstring(s)
print(t)
```

but  i got error : **TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object**. (i'm sorry im a newbie in NLP)

Comment: you have to read data from file - `s.read()`. You need: `t = ree.fromstring(s.read())`

Comment: BTW: it is preferred to use `repr(t)` instead of `t.__repr__()`

Comment: Where does the `.bracket` file come from?

Comment: @furas i tried, but got different error "ValueError: Tree.read(): expected 'end-of-string' but got '(SINV' . apparently, because it tried to read the next row

Comment: then use `for line in s: t = Tree.fromstring(line) print(t)` to read every line separatelly. OR read all to list `all_lines = s.readlines()` and later use `for`-loop to work with every line separatelly. In both situation you would have to put `t` in list to keep all `Trees`

Answer (score 1):

If each line in the file is bracketed tree, simply iterate through the file and store the `nltk.Tree` objects in a list.

```
from nltk import Tree

my_trees = []

with open('myfile.bracket') as fin:
    for line in fin:
       my_trees.append(Tree.fromstring(line))
```